# label all vertices in polygon plot

Tags: graphics, labeling

Let's say I have the following plot
`Graphics[{Opacity[0.2], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {4, 4}]}]`

And I want to label all vertices on the graph to give their coordinates, in this case, `Point(0,0)` as `"P1"`, `Point(0,4)` as `"P2"`...

In general, I want to write a function:
`plotPolygonWithLabel[polygon_, label_]:=...`

where `label_` is the array like `{"P1", "P2", }` here

Comment: Qiang, you forgot about these old posts?

Answer (score 10):

A slightly generalized version of Kuba's answer, by placing labels along the angular bisectors, which I think can handle most simply irregular polygons:

```
Clear[offsetFunc]
offsetFunc[pts : {Repeated[_List, {3}]}] :=
 Normalize[Most[Cross[{0, 0, 1},
                      Append[Total[Normalize /@ Differences[pts]], 0]
                     ]]]

Clear[labeledPolygon]
labeledPolygon[points_, labels_, offset_: 1] :=
 {
  Polygon@points,
  Text[Style[#1, Red, Bold],
       #2[[2]],
       offset offsetFunc[#2]] & @@@
   ({labels, Partition[points, 3, 1, {2, 2}]}\[Transpose])
  }
```

Example:

```
points = Table[RandomReal[{1, 3}] {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 π, π/10}] // Most;

labels = Table["P" <> ToString[t], {t, Length@points}];

Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Lighter@Blue, Thick}], labeledPolygon[points, labels, 2]}]
```

[image: example]

It may not perform well on non-simple polygon:

[image: counter example]

Answer (score 9):

There are many methodst to achieve that, You can start with this:

```
points = Table[2 {Cos@t, Sin@t}, {t, 0, 2 Pi - .2 Pi, .2 Pi}]
labels = Table["P" <> ToString[t], {t, Length@points}]

 f[points_, labels_] :=With[{O = Mean@points}, 
  Graphics[{Polygon@points, 
    Text[#1, #2] & @@@ ({labels, ((.2 + Norm[# - O]) ( 
          Normalize[# - O]) + O) & /@ points}\[Transpose])}]]

f[points,labels]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A different approach, but needs tweaking for graphical perfection:

```
plotPolygonWithLabel[polygon_, label_, fontSize_] := 
 {Polygon[polygon],
  MapThread[
   {EdgeForm[Thin],
     FaceForm[White],
     Disk[#1, (fontSize + 12)/72],
     Text[Style[#2, Black, fontSize, 
       FontFamily -> "Helvetica Bold", 
       Background -> White], #1]} & , 
   {polygon, label}]}

(* borrowing from Silvia ... *)
points = Table[
   RandomReal[{-3, 3}] {2 Cos[t], 2 Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi], Pi/5}];

labels = Table["P" <> ToString[t], {t, Length@points}];

Graphics[{plotPolygonWithLabel[points, labels, 14]}]
```

[image: alternative label style]

Answer (score 3):

#### `PathGraph`

You can use `PathGraph` or `Graph` with all the convenient options to style the labels, and add the polygon using `Prolog`:

```
ClearAll[labeledPolygonF]
labeledPolygonF[dir_: Opacity[.5, Blue], o1 : OptionsPattern[]][pts_, 
  lbls_, o2 : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 PathGraph[lbls, VertexCoordinates -> pts, o2, 
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> Large, 
  EdgeStyle -> Opacity[0], GraphStyle -> "DiagramGold", 
  Prolog -> Graphics[{dir, Polygon@pts}, o1][[1]]]
```

Alternatively, you can use `Graph` with the first argument `UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[lbls, 2, 1]` to get the same results.

Silvia's example:

```
SeedRandom[1]
points = Table[RandomReal[{1, 3}] {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 π, π/10}] // Most;
labels = Table["P" <> ToString[t], {t, Length@points}];

labeledPolygonF[][points, labels]
```

[image]

```
labeledPolygonF[Opacity[.5, Green]][points, labels, 
 VertexShapeFunction -> "Capsule", VertexSize -> 1, 
 VertexStyle -> Red, VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[14, White]]
```

[image]

Since  `labeledPolygonF` gives a `Graph` you have access to a number of conveninent functions in a right-click menu. For example, in the first example above, you can change the `GraphStyle` by selecting `GraphStyle >> SmallNetwork` on the right-click menu to get

[image]

If you need a `Graphics` object you can use

```
Show @ labeledPolygonF[...]
```

cormullion's example:

```
SeedRandom[12345]
points2 = Table[RandomReal[{-3, 3}] {2 Cos[t], 2 Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 π, π/5}];
labels2 = Table["P" <> ToString[t], {t, Length@points2}];

labeledPolygonF[Opacity[.8, Yellow], ImageSize -> 500][points2, labels2, 
    VertexSize -> .7, VertexStyle -> Blue, 
    VertexShapeFunction -> "Hexagon",  VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[White, Medium]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
points = RandomReal[{1, 3}, 20] CirclePoints[20.];

labels = Table["P" <> ToString[t], {t, Length@points}];

Graphics[{{Opacity[0.5], Polygon@points}, MapThread[Text, {labels, points}]}]

Show[Graphics[{Opacity[0.5], Polygon@points}], 
  ListPlot[points -> labels, LabelingFunction -> Center]]
```

[image]