# Angles inside of Voronoi mesh cells

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh

How can I determine the angles belonging to the vertices of each interior Voronoi mesh cell?

```
SeedRandom[314];
pts = RandomReal[5, {20, 2}];
vor = VoronoiMesh[pts, {{0, 5}, {0, 5}}];
vm = Graphics[{White, EdgeForm[Black], MeshPrimitives[vor, 2]}];
vmInterior = 
  Graphics[{LightBlue, EdgeForm[Black], 
    MeshPrimitives[vor, {2, "Interior"}]}];
Show[vm, vmInterior, Graphics[{Orange, Point[pts]}], Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Here I have marked manually as example one of the angels $\alpha$ of a single mesh cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give all the interior angles (thanks J.M. for finding my mistake)

```
VectorAngle[#1 - #2, #3 - #2] & @@@ Partition[#, 3, 1, {1, 1}] & /@ 
 MeshPrimitives[vor, {2, "Interior"}][[All, 1]]
(* {{2.52338, 0.458066, 1.70496, 1.59678}, {2.16596, 1.13255, 
  1.49028, 1.4944}, {2.76314, 1.73676, 1.3406, 2.81003, 
  0.774249}, {1.59378, 2.11081, 1.88852, 1.9605, 1.87116}, {2.65508, 
  2.79652, 2.45916, 2.25544, 1.34444, 1.78211, 2.41521}, {1.92314, 
  3.01509, 2.22179, 2.6078, 2.31291, 2.30653, 1.32071}, {2.2712, 
  2.64414, 2.32233, 2.15127, 1.68457, 1.64889, 2.98556}} *)
```

Thanks to RunnyKine for shortening the code.

But the list of angles is only so useful in my opinion, until you have a graphical way of showing the angles with the polygons.  Borrowing from Silvia's [code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26927/9490) we can make this function,

```
angleLabeledPolygon[Polygon[pts__]] := Module[{angles},
  angles = 
   VectorAngle[#1 - #2, #3 - #2] & @@@ Partition[pts, 3, 1, {1, 1}];
  Graphics[{LightBlue, Polygon@pts,
     Text[Style[#1, Red, Bold],
              #2[[2]],

       Normalize[
        Most[Cross[{0, 0, 1}, 
          Append[Total[Normalize /@ Differences[#2]], 
           0]]]]] & @@@
     ({angles, 
        Partition[pts, 3, 1, {1, 1}]}\[Transpose])
    }
   ]
  ]

Show[angleLabeledPolygon@#, ImageSize -> 400] & /@ 
 MeshPrimitives[vor, {2, "Interior"}]
```

[image]

Comment: You can replace `First /@ (List @@@ MeshPrimitives[vor, {2, "Interior"}])` with `MeshPrimitives[vor, {2, "Interior"}][[All, 1]]`

Comment: @RunnyKine - Thanks, I used to never use `First` and always do the `Part` specifications.  But using this site, it kinda rubbed off on me

Comment: There are a few angles which are greater than 90 deg. That means VectorAngle should show values > 1. The maximum of your values is 0.676899 which corresponds to less than 45 degree. I think there must be a small error, or ?

Comment: @mrz, yes, that's because the answer forgot to compensate for the fact that the corners are not centered at the origin. Here's the correct version: `VectorAngle[#1 - #2, #3 - #2] & @@@ Partition[#, 3, 1, {2, -2}] & /@ 
 MeshPrimitives[vor, {2, "Interior"}][[All, 1]]`.

Comment: @J. M., Yes ... thanks for your help... now the values are as expected

Comment: Thanks for the great solution ... could you mention the compensation by J. M. in your answer?

Comment: I've said it before, but someone could build an entire reputation score on this site by following @J.M. around and posting his comments as answers, and I'm not above doing that as well.  See the edit above, I think it would be neat to have the angles show up **inside** the polygon so that you could have it in the larger plot, but then the angle labels would get crowded in certain areas.

Comment: Imagine I would have only hexagons with a certain disorder and I want  to give information about the mean of all angles with its standard deviation (or a histogram of all inner angles) - this is a helpful value. With your code I produced the following plot
http://goo.gl/HmB3rm (example for experimental 2D hexagonal plasma crystal data)